# How do I point roundcube directory to dns record?

Tags: apache2, roundcube

I have a Windows server which hosts the DNS server. I also have a Linux server hosting Apache and Roundcube.

I made two a records in the DNS server: one is `intranet.example.com` for Apache and the other is `webmail.example.com` for webmail.

Both having the same IP address. So they now point to the same website.

How do I make the `webmail.example.com` points to the Roundcube directory?

Comment: Look for VirtualHosts configuration of Apache : one for webmail.example.com and one for intranet.example.com

Comment: Thanks for opening my eye up on this. Done some research on the internet about virtual hosts. And I just got the concept of it tq very much